# What platform (server installed on ubuntu vs ubuntu server) to prefer for website development?

Tags: apache, web, glassfish, ubuntu-server, web-development-server

I am developing a website which is supposed to have blogging capabilities (which I aim to achieve via wordpress) and a CRM based upon jsp and oracle express (as the website will be deployed over linux server, sql server is not an option).

For development should I choose a server to be installed on a linux machine or should I use linux server? I am sorry if they are very different things and not comparable but I went through both of theirs documentation but couldn't figure out anything.
If I should go for some server to installed on ubuntu, what server should i go for?
I hear that glassfish has much higher support for jsp rather than apache.

Please also keep in mind that the website will go o live on a linux server so please suggest based upon problems or ease of deployment on later stage.

I have a deadline to meet and the people who gave me this work have not been much generous with time. I do not have much linux experience so please pardon my lack of knowledge of the platform.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of confusion in your post. Based on your lack of experience with GNU/Linux, I would suggest you use desktop Ubuntu.

The difference between Ubuntu server and Ubuntu desktop is that the server edition is targetted to experienced users, so you get a very minimal distribution. No GUI, nothing preinstalled except the bare minimum.

As for your comment about Apache/Glassfish, the two aren't comparable. Apache is the name of the open source community which looks after a lot of products. Very often people call Apache's httpd just "apache", which is a web server. Glassfish is a Java EE application server (Oracle's reference implementation) so probably a good place to start with Java EE.